# Is there a status message to let others know what I am doing either busy, away, or something else?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a status message to let others know what I am doing either busy, away, or something else?

Comment: I assume you mean in chat?

Comment: twitoverflow! :)

Comment: @Neil, for the forum. When others answer our questions and we are away, we can put a note so they know what we are doing.

Comment: maybe look for stackbook or faceoverflow.

Comment: Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow [is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Comment: @Peter: Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow can be categorized as a forum but with a rule where each question is mapped to zero or more answers or comments. Not saying a forum seems a marketing jargon. :-)

Comment: @Peter: In my profile, there is a Venn-diagram representing that SE/SO is a forum. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The only way someone will know you're active is either by seeing you post, or looking at your profile at the **seen X mins ago**.

If you really wanted to, I don't think there are any restrictions on how often you can edit your profiles About Me section.

Comment: Only rate-limited section of the profile is the Display Name.

Comment: I think no body will often check About Me section. Because it is not usual way. :)

Comment: @xport That's... pretty much the sum of it, though. Stack Overflow is not a social gathering place - it is a place to find answers to questions. If you want to meet up with people, use the Chat, not the main Q&A.

Comment: @xport: that's because *no one cares.*