# Training users to use a Q&A website

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, voting

*I hope I have chosen the right stack exchange site to ask this question, please let me know if im wrong.  I could ask on the OSQA site, but I think I will get better answers here.*

I have fallen in love with the SE alternative approach to forums.
As a result, I have setup a Q&A site based on [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) to try and mimic SE.

- We are a software vendor with a client base of around 200 people.
- We have a dozen developers and dozen support analysts.
- We intend to use OSQA to allow clients to ask Qs, and support/dev to answer the Qs.
- We also expect that our clients will participate in helping each other, and hence OSQA similar reputation system to SE is good bait to encourage this helping.

So. I have it all setup and ready to go.
My biggest fear is that I think without proper training/guidance, the thing could turn into a big mess.
i.e. People not understanding how SE sites work, and treating it like any other forum.
I was thinking about implementing phpBB instead, but I think (+ [research](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stack-exchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum)) with some good guidance, our users will get better benefit from a Q&A site.

To achieve this:

- I will beef the default [OSQA FAQ](http://meta.osqa.net/faq/) up with some more emphasis on 'how to ask Qs'
- I will put together a blog post/screencast on how to ask a typical question, change settings, explain when to vote up/down, flag, etc.

**Can anyone point me to some great resources on how to prepare for this?

 - Perhaps some good articles on Coding Horror?

 - Ideas to emphasise the ethos of SE sites and how they are better than forum sites (in most scenarios)**

*I feel a bit cheeky for asking for help on what could be called a competitors platform (?), (I know [Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/my-software-is-being-pirated.html) has discussed this) but the principles of the platforms are what im after, and in my video/blog post I will be crediting SE and encouraging people to check them out*

Comment: As an aside: [training users to use paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635). ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wealth of resources on this site alone that could help you define good criteria for asking the right questions on your Q&A site.  In addition, the Stack Overflow Blog has tons of posts derived from the learning experience of Stack Exchange over the years, such as [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

You can also view the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) of any one of the sites on the Stack Exchange network for some information on the goals of the Stack Exchange network.  I believe the FAQ clearly explains the goals of the Q&A platform.

Most importantly, the documentation will only get you so far.  Despite all of the experience learned by the Stack Exchange team, and despite all of the well-written published material on what makes good Q&A sites, I'm still surprised when I see people challenging the status quo in an attempt to degrade this network into a discussion forum.   In short, all of the documentation in the world won't help you if you don't have the right people seeding your site with great questions and answers.