# I was down-voted by 6 pts, then they were restored extremely quickly. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, down-votes, new-users

I understand there are similar questions here, I am asking specifically about the issues of this one.

Just want to know what exactly just went on. I DID lose my cool. I have an idea why my rep was restored. Just don't want to assume. I will stop with these questions, just want to understand exactly what's going on.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749577/how-to-show-wall-post-from-page-on-facebook-in-my-site/16749602#16749602

Comment: The answer was deleted and the reputation lost due to the downvotes on it was restored then.

Comment: OH, but I didn't delete it. Why did someone else delete it?

Comment: Vague link only answers are not considered good answers. Three trusted (reputation 20K+) users deleted it.

Comment: I flagged the original question as a duplicate and provided the link - which is what was annoying me the most.. and I saw someone answer a similar question in the same format earlier.. so you see I am confused.. I wouldn't have answered it like that id I hadn't seen the other question (then closed) and answered in the same fashion without issue.. I think my brain is special.. (and not in a good way), I'll say thank you now Marint, rather than start a discussion in chat, cheers :-) Yvette

Comment: If the link was to an extremely relevant good quality resource that exactly answered the OP's question then it *might* be tolerated but generally speaking new answers that consist of just links with no explanatory text will probably be deleted.

Comment: I'm starting to think I don't belong on these forums :( I just can't seem to get it right.. another new qanda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749717/how-to-show-facebook-page-posts-on-my-webste he used a link to the same site, except found the actual page..

Comment: That user has a grand total of 51 rep and has only ever submitted 10 answers. Unfortunately they too are probably not yet aware that link only answers are widely discouraged. See the [link-only-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-only-answers?sort=votes&pagesize=30) tag for previous discussion on these.

Comment: yes, the same person who berated me has commented there and done nothing,. you see, I am sensitive and being female- it's intimidating on a site like this  - also I am learning.. I feel so stupid when I make mistakes, but figure it is better to try and risk, and learn than just watch,, Is it??? Also, they are duplicate questions and it's driving me crazy (i'm not sure why) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163858/how-to-show-my-facebook-wall-on-my-website

Comment: "I'm starting to think I don't belong on these forums" Maybe, maybe not. But you're asking how things work here, and that's promising.

Comment: The other link-only answer is slightly better because it answers the question directly: "Q: Is there a tutorial I can follow? A: [Yes.] Here is the link for the tutorial." The question *specifically* asked for a link, and received it. (On the other hand asking for a link is not a very good question so hopefully it'll get closed soon.)

Comment: It was closed and since I've worked out my problems, I have gained over 50 rep on SO!!! hey I am so excited. I'm taking my time to answer questions and not worrying whether I don't get marked as best answer, but am focused on being helpful! yay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am answering my own question - so as to demonstrate that this is a learning process and that there was value given in the comments by my fellow members, in this case Martin Smith.

I am taking care not to assume that other answers I see on the SO forum are regarded as "good" answers. I have made the mistake of seeing other answers and taking the same approach of just adding a link, with little to no comment.

The following quotes are taken from the comments under my question:

> Vague link only answers are not considered good answers. Three trusted (reputation 20K+) users deleted it.
>
> If the link was to an extremely relevant good quality resource that exactly answered the OP's question then it might be tolerated but generally speaking new answers that consist of just links with no explanatory text will probably be deleted

I think it is important to try and maintain an emotional detachment from the forum. As comments and downvotes can be taken personally, when in reality, they are made from people globally, faceless and are 'usually' made with good intent. This keeps the forum well researched and it's members best educated.

The other point I did not realise was the following. Again I quote form Martin Smith's comments:

> The answer was deleted and the reputation lost due to the downvotes on it was restored then. – Martin Smith

In this case it was a blessing it was deleted by the more experienced SO members, as my reputation was restored.

Upon reflection, the hardest part is to admit, that the down votes I have received had ALL been justified. For most human beings it is hard to accept our failings, more so in a pubic forum.

So I am writing this on the Meta site, as I think it might help some fellow members, as we struggle to find our place on SO.

I want to put in an update, since clarifying the quality of my answer I have gained over 50 rep on SO!!! hey I am so excited. I'm taking my time to answer questions and not worrying whether I don't get marked as best answer, but am focused on being helpful.It is such a relief to get the priority of answering questions in order. It is not about ME getting reputation, it is about offering helpful answers!

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Comment: it's a question answer site?

Comment: Being a Q&A site and not a forum: that's why it works so well and provides **lots** of knowledge. And answering is a speed ticket to  more knowledge, perfect!

Comment: @brasofilo I learn more from the answers I post, than the questions, even the poor ones!